# Send a file to telegram bot, so telegram bot send it to discord webhook (python)

Tags: python, discord, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to make so when telegram bot ask for a certain file, and user send it, discord webhook  send it to discord channel. I new in the coding and I decided to make my telegram bot, so I really need help. I imported dhooks, and webhook from it. I made this code

```
@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    text = message.text
    hook.send(text)
```

It sends any text that user says to telegram bot to discord webhook. But I am confused how to repeat something like that with files. I tried doing that code, which reacts to only if document sent to bot and which gets into file variable the file itself.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def get_user_text(message):
    file = message.document
    hook.send(file)
```

When I run code nothing happens, but whenever I send the file to bot with this code, error happens.

```
TypeError: Object of type Document is not JSON serializable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).

The TypeError you are getting is because the hook expects a [`dhooks.file.File`](https://dhooks.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#dhooks.Webhook.send) object, but you are sending a `Document` object instead (`message.document`).

According to the [dhooks documentation](https://dhooks.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#dhooks.File) you will need either a file path or a binary stream for the file to create the `File` object:

```py
file = File('path/to/file.png')  

hook.send('Look at this:', file=file)
```

OR

```py
response = requests.get(message.document.url)
file = File(BytesIO(response.content))

hook.send('Another one:', file=file)
```